# Stick Force Layout with D3js V4

Tags: d3.js

I noticed that the source code for D3 V4 does not have d.fixed has a setting for disabling the force simulation.  How does one create fixed nodes as in the example below with v4?

```
//from line 6299 of v3
if (o.fixed) {
      o.x = o.px;
      o.y = o.py;
    } else {
      o.x -= (o.px - (o.px = o.x)) * friction;
      o.y -= (o.py - (o.py = o.y)) * friction;
    }
```

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4e4a31f132bc6b27634234dc935a7252

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `o.fx` and `o.fy`. From the docs:

> To fix a node in a given position, you may specify two additional properties:
>
> - fx - the node’s fixed x-position
> - fy - the node’s fixed y-position

https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md